# how could I sort hundreds of images by their content

Tags: shell-script, images

I m looking for a solution to sort hundreds of images by their content;
of course, I will script around the solution to automate that work.

I know I can use metadata to separate draws and photos. But my need is to sort all by the real content of image itself ;  apple goes to apple images list ; bikes go to bikes image list ; people go to people image list and so on.

I googled for a while *(since last weekend exactly)* , but I find nothing about that.

Is there a solution for my needs ? *(I can accept a solution with many steps, if so I will write a script to run them)*

Comment: check out https://opencv.org/

Comment: Image recognition is massively complex and [still makes a lot of errors](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2018/1/12/16882408/google-racist-gorillas-photo-recognition-algorithm-ai).  "Hundreds" isn't that many.  For the time / effort you might be better sorting by your own eyes rather than AI.

Comment: On a more serious note I suggest looking into whether or not there is an API for Google Photo or similar tools.  Stand alone desktop apps are not likely to be successful. https://cloud.google.com/vision